# Animation of DialogFragment using Material Motion Fade

Tags: android, animation, material-ui, android-dialogfragment

I have a task to make an animation of the appearance/disappear DialogFragment (date picker SlyCalendarDialog) using Material Motion Fade animation. There is a GIF in the documentation where this is implemented https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion#fade, but I don’t understand how it make. I can animate the view in the window, but the DialogFragment is a new window. Сode below doesn't work

```
 TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(sceneRoot, MaterialFade().apply{
                duration = 200
                addTarget(R.id.slyCalendar)})
 SlyCalendarDialog().show(childFragmentManager)
```